# Delete lines in a file containing argument passed on command line

Tags: database, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to delete specific lines based on the argument passed in.

My data.txt file contains

```
Cpu 500 64 6
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128
```

My del.sh contains

```
myvar=$1

sed'/$myvar/d' data.txt > temp.txt
mv temp.txt > data.txt
```

but it just prints every line in temp.txt to data.txt....however

```
sed '/64/d' data.txt > temp.txt
```

will do the correct data transfer (but I don't want to hardcode 64), I feel like there's some kind of syntax error with the argument. Any input please

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the single quotes, change them to double quotes.  Variables inside single quotes are not interpolated, so you are sending the *literal string* `$myvar` to `sed`, instead of the *value of* `$myvar`.

Change:

```
sed '/$myvar/d' data.txt
```

to:

```
sed "/$myvar/d" data.txt
```

**Note:** You will run into issues when `$myvar` contains regular expression meta characters or forward slashes as pointed out [in this response from Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19051316/21926).  If you are not in complete control of your input you will need to find another avenue to accomplish this.

Comment: Try it when myvar contains a `/` or one of several other characters that command will produce unexpected results and/or error messages for.

Comment: That just changes the problem. Try it now when `$1` contains `\/`. This is a fundamental problem with sed's syntax and you cannot solve it by figuring out which chars to escape because doing that creates other issues. sed just isn't the right tool for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is undesirable behavior:

```
$ cat file
Cpu 500 64 6
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128

$ myvar=6
$ sed "/$myvar/d" file
Monitor 22 42 50

$ myvar=/
$ sed "/$myvar/d" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `/'

$ myvar=.
$ sed "/$myvar/d" file
$
```

Try this instead:

```
$ myvar=6
$ awk -v myvar="$myvar" '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ($i == myvar) next }1' file
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128

$ myvar=/
$ awk -v myvar="$myvar" '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ($i == myvar) next }1' file
Cpu 500 64 6
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128

$ myvar=.
$ awk -v myvar="$myvar" '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ($i == myvar) next }1' file
Cpu 500 64 6
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128
```

and if you think you can just escape the `/`s and use sed, you can't because you might be adding a 2nd backslash to one already present:

```
$ foo='\/'
$ myvar=${foo//\//\\\/}
$ sed "/$myvar/d" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `/'

$ awk -v myvar="$myvar" '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ($i == myvar) next }1' file
Cpu 500 64 6
Monitor 22 42 50
Game 32 64 128
```

This is simply NOT a job you can in general do with sed due to it's syntax and it's restriction of only allowing REs in it's search.

Comment: No, it's not (try it - you'll see), and slashes aren't the only characters you need to worry about, see above for a couple of other issues.

Comment: No, you can't just escape the slash. See the comment I just posted under your answer. I also updated my answer to show explicitly why.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work either as it would delete lines containing `64` if you were looking for lines containing `6`. I'm not simply arguing semantics, this is one of those problems where there's many proposed solutions that look right and work on the posted sample data and then a year later the "solution" wipes out your whole file or directory and you don't know why.

Comment: Right, the OP didn't tell us much about his requirements but he does show that he's writing a script so I'm just making what I think are a couple of very reasonable assumptions about what he'd want to happen if that script is called with arguments he may not have foreseen and which can cause unexpected and unnecessary problems with a sed solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my response to reflect the potential danger with using `sed` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use awk to do the same,

```
awk '!/'$myvar'/' data.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt data.txt
```

Use `-i` option in addition to what @SeanBright proposed. Then you won't need `> temp.txt and mv temp.txt data.txt`.

```
sed -i "/$myvar/d" data.txt
```

Comment: I like the -i! Thanks guys.

Comment: Never use the style of awk command posted here. It has as even more issues then the posted sed command does for various input characters and, unlike sed, it's not necessary to expose yourself to those issues with awk.